# How can I use split but skip html/javascript/php and other inner tags?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

My code inserts a HTML content after X number of words of a blog post. The code works, but there is a problem: It strips everything it finds on the way, even javascript, html, whatever.

The `if (index == 2)` counts the first two words of the code, then insert the HTML (In this case an image) after those words, but it makes no distinction of html or pure text.
I found a topic here saying I should use something like this:

```
result = subject.match(/<\s*(\w+\b)(?:(?!<\s*\/\s*\1\b)[\s\S])*<\s*\/\s*\1\s*>|\S+/g);
```

But I don't know how to implement it.

Basically, I need the code to count every single word, but skip any tags like `<\ " " ? --> <!-- />`

Fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/kvenmL07/

HTML:

```
 <div style="width:450px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto" class="newsitem_text">
    <div style="width:350px; margin-left:auto; margin-right:auto">

    Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec pellentesque urna eu pulvinar maximus. Sed elit nunc, vestibulum ut eros vitae, pellentesque rhoncus ipsum. In et metus non diam porttitor maximus iaculis nec lectus. Quisque sodales scelerisque auctor. Nam rutrum venenatis eros, eu condimentum erat placerat ut. Pellentesque sed tempus sem, eu viverra ipsum. Vestibulum nec turpis convallis, dapibus massa vitae, posuere mauris. Suspendisse mattis tincidunt lorem. Aliquam erat volutpat. Nullam at tincidunt erat, maximus laoreet ipsum.

    Quisque nunc neque, semper tincidunt placerat eget, blandit a ante. Suspendisse pulvinar, velit eu ultrices pulvinar, lacus sapien tincidunt ipsum, eget sollicitudin mauris eros molestie ex. Etiam quis orci dui. Phasellus vestibulum mollis molestie. Nam condimentum ornare nisl, sed finibus risus tempus vel. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Interdum et malesuada fames ac ante ipsum primis in faucibus.

    Vestibulum eget ullamcorper lorem. Aliquam mollis elit in sem dapibus dapibus. Proin vel massa a arcu dictum tincidunt in ut ante. Sed feugiat tempus dictum. Praesent in leo ullamcorper, sodales turpis et, vehicula tellus. Duis pellentesque dui ac turpis tristique imperdiet. Sed sed orci lectus.

    Suspendisse non egestas sem, sed tincidunt sem. Etiam laoreet dui sem. Mauris hendrerit massa tempus, euismod arcu sit amet, eleifend quam. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Phasellus id fringilla mauris. Cras dapibus non lacus at finibus. Nullam vitae sagittis neque. Mauris libero velit, interdum non vehicula non, lacinia non augue. Maecenas elementum lacinia interdum.

    Morbi eget mollis nisl. Integer accumsan condimentum tellus, lacinia pellentesque urna volutpat a. Nullam semper sem et erat commodo sollicitudin. Proin rhoncus felis eu aliquam venenatis. Class aptent taciti sociosqu ad litora torquent per conubia nostra, per inceptos himenaeos. Nulla pretium velit eu molestie condimentum. Vestibulum vitae velit mi. Integer nec leo quam. Nam pulvinar ligula congue consectetur tristique. Donec placerat faucibus diam sit amet fermentum. Ut id pellentesque risus. Nunc lacus orci, rhoncus ut risus sed, mattis posuere tellus. Nulla pellentesque eros sed neque consectetur dictum.</div></div>
```

Jquery:

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.3/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script type="text/javascript">
 jQuery(function($) {

var wordList = $(".newsitem_text").html().split(' ');


var newHtml = ' ';

$.each(wordList, function(index, word){
  newHtml += ' ' + word;
  if (index == 2) {
    newHtml += '<img src="https://www.google.com.br/logos/doodles/2015/adolphe-saxs-201st-birthday-6443879796572160.2-res.png" />'     
  }        
})
;

$(".newsitem_text").html(newHtml);

});


</script>
```

Answer (score 2):

If you use .text() instead of .html() it will not show any of the tags.. for instance:

```
    <div id="test" class="test2">
       <span>this is a test</span>
    </div>
```

then

```
var mytext = $("#test").text();
```

mytext would equal "this is a test";

Comment: Already tried that. Use that in the fiddle and you'll see what happens.

Comment: It transforms the text into raw text.

Answer (score 0):

```
word = word.replace(/<\/?[\w#"'-=:; {},.\r\n]+\/?>/g, '\n');
word = word.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, '');
```

probably you only need the first line. add this after the $each. line and before newHtml += line.

----------------- edit

Probably I misunderstood it first time. Try to remove tags first before split()

```
jQuery(function($) {

    //var wordList = $(".newsitem_text").html().split(' ');
    var wordList = $(".newsitem_text").html();
    wordList = wordList.replace(/<\/?[\w#"'-=:; {},.\r\n]+\/?>/g, '\n');
    wordList = wordList.split(' ')

    var newHtml = ' ';

    $.each(wordList, function(index, word){
      newHtml += ' ' + word;
      if (index == 2) {
       newHtml += '<img src="https://www.google.com.br/logos/doodles/2015/adolphe-saxs-201st-birthday-6443879796572160.2-res.png" />'
      }        
    })
    ;

    $(".newsitem_text").html(newHtml);

});
```

Comment: I'll probably need both, the page where I need to put this code has all sort of characters, including that space described in the second line. Thx, I'll give it a try and give you a feedback.

Comment: By the way, it will skip the tags and the code withing them, or just the tags? Because may skip `<javascript>`, but insert the content right after that part.

Comment: You mean it should be like this? `$.each(wordList, function(index, word) {
  word = word.replace(/<\/?[\w#"'-=:; {},.\r\n]+\/?>/g, '\n');
word = word.replace(/&nbsp;/gi, '');
  
 newHtml += ' ' + word;`

Comment: Like replacing for a blank space? isn't there a way to just skip them? For example:
`<script>the js code</code>--- skip the script tags --- The words --- Insert the banner here ---`